# How to test Solid State Relay Testing

Tags: components

I am a newbie to electronics and hope someone can help.  I am looking to test a SSR for my own experimentation to see if I understand this correctly.

I have a SSR for 120 AC. (I am not plugging in for fear of not understanding yet) When I apply the small DC (say 3-9 V) the connects for 120 should become closed if I understand right and should have continuity.  So basically I am trying to test this SSR by applying a small DC voltage across the DC pins and then testing the continuity across the AC pins.

I am not getting continuity across the AC pins when applying DC voltage across the DC pins.

Am I not getting a closed circuit because there is not enough load across the AC pins?

Thanks for any help.

Comment: Is this a question about SSRs in general or do you have a particular SSR in mind? If the latter, please include a schematic and/or datasheet for it.

Comment: I would say in general.  I have a yellow SSR with 2 DC pins and 2 AC pins.  thanks for any help understanding this.

Comment: Your description of how the SSR works appears correct. How are you testing for continuity? What do you measure when you say you are "not getting continuity"? You may need to post a link to the datasheet and possibly a schematic of your test circuit to figure out the problem.

Comment: Ken, keep in mind that there are 2 distinct types of SSR.  (1) There are SCR or TRIAC solid state relays.  These work only for AC.  They open when the AC current crosses zero.  Since DC current doesn't necessarily cross zero, this type of SSR can't switch DC.  (2) There are MOSFET solid state relays that work for DC.  (finally) You should carefully read the datasheet to see what's sort of SSR you have got.

Comment: Thanks Null, by "not getting continuity" I mean that on my multimeter the continuity indicator does not say the AC circuit has been closed once a small dc current was applied to the DC pins.  Does this make sense and thanks for any help!

Comment: Hi Nick, Thanks for the reply, but your speak is over my head.  Sorry for not being able to under help.  I will definitely try to track down the datasheet!

Comment: It's ALIVE!  Ok, I have it working!  I guess the SSR doesn't work unless it's under load.  Once I had the SSR connected to 110 and added a small ac the SSR comes alive.  Thanks everyone for any help and not flaming.

Answer (score 2):

It's ALIVE! Ok, I have it working! I guess the SSR doesn't work unless it's under load. Once I had the SSR connected to 110 and added a small ac the SSR comes alive. Thanks everyone for any help and not flaming. –

Comment: Yup, the AC SSRs won't work unless they have some substantial voltage across them- a multimeter isn't enough. Glad you figured it out.